# PHP - Split string containing newline and print

Tags: php

Why is the following code not working...?

```
$test = "hello \n world \n !";
foreach(explode("\n",$test) as $line){
echo $line;
}
```

It prints

```
hello world !
```

Instead of

```
hello 
world
!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to echo `<br />`

> The HTML `<br />` element produces a line break in text (carriage-return).
>   It is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of
>   lines is significant.

```
$test = "hello \n world \n !";
foreach(explode("\n",$test) as $line){
    echo $line;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

doc: [`<br />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

---

Another option is to use `nl2br` to inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

```
$test = "hello \n world \n !";
echo nl2br($test);
```

Doc: [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br)

Comment: Strange, I already answered the question and no upvote for me.

Comment: Your answer is also great. I hope someone will upvote your answer too. And this is not really a race, who answers first will get the upvote :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Totally forgot that i'm working with HTML. Hah. Upvoted both answers.

Comment: Happy to help @Leo505 :)

Comment: Yup, nothing in the question at all about HTML output.

Comment: @Progrock then why you add more answer? I think OP already received solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Add new line to Browser Output via HTML**

In HTML, you need to add line break for new line via HTML Tag. This will not appear as required output if there is line break in text/string.

`<br>` used to add single line break.

Replace

```
echo $line;
```

Into

```
echo $line."<br>";
```

2. **Add new line to *string/source code***

If you need to add new line into source code only then replace `echo $line;` with `echo $line."\n";`

`\n` is used into double quotes for new line.

3. **Add new line to Browser Output via PHP**

Anyways an other way to do this via PHP is to use PHP's built-in method [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = "hello \n world \n !";
foreach(explode("\n",$test) as $line){
echo $line;
}
```

The result is:

```
hello  world  !
```

Basically you have split on the newlines, and the newlines are not included as you print out each split part.

Comment: Thi is only partially true and should be the accepted answer if you add that nl2br() should be used for it to work +1

Comment: @AmrBerag as commented, OP never said anything about rendering in a html viewer.  Why is this only partially true?

Comment: It is implicitly understood after OP accepted the answer with br **HTML** tag  after which i notified you to improve your answer because i felt it is the only one (beside my answer)answering the question "Why is the following code not working...?"

Answer (score 0):

Use nl2br($line)  and replace the delimiter with empty space.This way your new line will be visible in html:

```
$test = "hello \n world \n !";
foreach(explode(" ",$test) as $line){
  echo nl2br($line);
}
```

will output:

`hello

world

!`

and the output html:

```
hello<br />
world<br />
!
```

Comment: OP already mark the answer. Do you think more answers are required? If yes, that is new in your answer?

Comment: Hello Hassan, its just another answer aimed more toward explaining why it didnt work and how to solve it and it is easier to inject more text between the lines this way and if I find time i will post 10 more separate answers. Why is it bothering you?